# Make Viewpager Top View (LinearLayout) Not Swipeable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented a ViewPager which I inflate views for every page since they are different, this works fine. I have a linearlayout with a height of 50dp ontop of each viewpager page which have the same buttons, I would like to prevent this view from sliding / swiping and would like for it to remain static just like the actionbar above it. I have attached a screenshot for clarity.

screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the `LinearLayout` within `inflateView1`, `inflateView2`, and `inflateView3`, could you pull it out and put it within the parent's view layout, i.e. where the ActionBar is?

In pseudo code:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Toolbar/>
    <LinearLayout id="@+id/buttonsLayout"/>
    <ViewPager/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then within your ViewPager views, just remove the `LinearLayout` with the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I ended up adding my buttons to the far right on the actionbar, I think this this is an even better approach.